# Can you add in-app purchases after an app has been submitted

Tags: ios

Im planning on submitting my app with iAds but no in-app purchases for removing iAds just yet due to me being frustrated with it so far, could i submit my app now and just add in-app purchases on my app later in time

Comment: Adding later means releasing a new version.

Comment: ops I posted for android.

Answer (score 1):

> **Rule:** In-App Purchases can only released with a new app version.

Just before you publish an app. version you select purchases(products) that you want to release with this version.

In your case, I believe that you didn't implement the In-App Purchase inside your current live app. therefore, you have to publish a new version anyway.

**Steps:**

> 1. Add In-App Purchase service into ItunesConnect.
> 2. Add your purchase. (Add it now for test while the implementation).
> 3. Implement and test In-App Purchase inside your app.
> 4. publish and select purchases to submit with the new release of the app.

Good Luck,